# mysql union get back Error 1022 — How can i fixed this?

Tags: mysql, union, mysql-error-1222

my weather schemes have two different tables rainfall and outside temp.

i try this :

```
SELECT 
 savetime
 ,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(savetime) as unixt
 ,(MAX(counteramount) - MIN(counteramount))*295/1000 as rainc 
 from rainfall 
 union 
 Select 
 savetime
 ,avg(weatherdata)as temp 
 FROM outside_temp 
 where savetime >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) 
 group by day(savetime)
```

but get back failure:
#1222 - The SELECT commands used return different numbers of fields

I have no Plan how to fix this...

Best regards
Quito

Comment: you have 2 SELECT statements and what Do you want to do with it?

Comment: target is query savetime rainc temp group by day, month etc by using the union command

Comment: please add your data as text and not as images see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNION has to have teh same number of columns, so add simpo,y alos a unixtome column and you are good

```
SELECT 
    savetime,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(savetime) AS unixt,
    (MAX(counteramount) - MIN(counteramount)) * 295 / 1000 AS rainc
    ,''
FROM
    rainfall 
UNION SELECT 
    savetime,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(savetime) AS unixt,
    ,''
    AVG(weatherdata) AS temp
FROM
    outside_temp
WHERE
    savetime >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY)
GROUP BY DAY(savetime)
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE outside_temp (
>   `savetime` DATETIME,
>   `weatherdata` FLOAT,
>   `newflag` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO outside_temp
>   (`savetime`, `weatherdata`, `newflag`)
> VALUES
>   ('2020-01-31 01:10:00', '8.9', '1'),
>   ('2020-01-31 03:25:00', '8.9', '1'),
>   ('2020-01-31 05:40:00', '9.1', '1'),
>   ('2020-01-31 00:10:00', '8.8', '1'),
>   ('2020-01-31 04:25:00', '9.3', '1'),
>   ('2020-01-31 00:55:00', '9', '1'),
>   ('2020-01-31 01:25:00', '8.9', '1'),
>   ('2020-01-31 00:25:00', '8.9', '1'),
>   ('2020-01-31 04:10:00', '9.3', '1');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE rainfall (
>   `savetime` VARCHAR(34),
>   `raincounter` INTEGER,
>   `counteramount` INTEGER,
>   `israining` INTEGER,
>   `newflag` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO rainfall
>   (`savetime`, `raincounter`, `counteramount`, `israining`, `newflag`)
> VALUES
>   ('2020-01-31 09:10:00', '2016', '37290', '0', '1'),
>   ('2020-01-31 16:56:00', '2016', '37290', '0', '1'),
>   ('2020-01-31 07:40:00', '2016', '37290', '0', '1'),
>   ('2020-01-31 05:10:00', '2016', '37290', '0', '1'),
>   ('2020-01-31 11:11:00', '2016', '37290', '0', '1'),
>   ('2020-01-31 15:11:00', '2016', '37290', '0', '1'),
>   ('2020-01-31 20:56:00', '2016', '37290', '0', '1'),
>   ('2020-01-31 11:41:00', '2016', '37290', '0', '1'),
>   ('2020-01-31 08:55:00', '2016', '37290', '0', '1'),
>   ('2020-01-31 15:41:00', '2016', '37290', '0', '1'),
>   ('2020-01-31 12:11:00', '2016', '37290', '0', '1');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     savetime_temp
>     ,AVG_temp
>     ,rainc
> FROM
> (SELECT 
>     DATE(savetime) DAY_temp
> ,MIN(savetime) savetime_temp
>     ,AVG(weatherdata) AS AVG_temp
> FROM
>     outside_temp
> WHERE
>     savetime >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 360 DAY)
> GROUP BY  DAte(savetime)) t1 
> INNER JOIN
> (SELECT 
>     DATE(savetime) DAY_rainc
>     ,MIN(savetime) savetime_rainc
>     ,(MAX(counteramount) - MIN(counteramount)) * 295 / 1000 AS rainc
>
> FROM
>     rainfall 
>  GROUP BY DAte(savetime)) t2
>  ON t1.DAY_temp = t2.DAY_rainc
> ```
>
> ```
> savetime_temp       |          AVG_temp |  rainc
> :------------------ | ----------------: | -----:
> 2020-01-31 00:10:00 | 9.011111047532824 | 0.0000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5f556a2f980da10b5f9466d56ea7e221)*

Comment: it works but iam missing the temp get savetime,unixt,rainc

Comment: if  you nned 5  column add simply `,''` at the pososition . but yiu can play around a bit s till you get it right, i would to be honest join the tbale instead of union

Comment: please add the data posted as text please, the join comand is savetome, but bith tomes aren't thesame see if Minutes fit and join them

Comment: not that what i expected….
savetime                          unixt                 rainc
2009-07-14 10:38:00 1247560680 11463.405000000

Comment: look at this questoon https://stackoverflow.com/q/63509229/5193536 . , there is everything as text and also the wanted result. i still don't know what you want

Comment: @Quito96 see my changed answer the you find your joined data. Don't forget to change the interval i had to increase it becasue if the date and instead of the svetime you should use DAY_temp

Comment: nbk, thanks a lot and now i see that the inner join is the better choice. I need savetime as  unixtime, how can i reached that?  Your sql inner join is really fast on my mysql server :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need the same number of column and matching data type   .. add null column if you have not enough columns

```
 SELECT 
    day(savetime)
    ,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(savetime) as unixt
    ,(MAX(counteramount) - MIN(counteramount))*295/1000 as rainc 
    , null  temp
    from rainfall 
    group by day(savetime)
 union 
 Select 
    day(savetime)
    , null
    , null
    ,avg(weatherdata) 
 FROM outside_temp 
 where savetime >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) 
 group by day(savetime)
```